Actix response function shows error in the IDE for sqlx query
I have a function:
pub async fn create_email(
    pool: web::Data<PgPool>,
    new_email: web::Json<CreateEmail>,
) -> impl Responder {
    let email = sqlx::query_as!(
        Email,
        r#"
        INSERT INTO emails (subscriber_id, email)
        VALUES ($1, $2)
        RETURNING id, subscriber_id, email
        "#,
        new_email.subscriber_id,
        new_email.email
    )
    .fetch_one(pool.get_ref())
    .await;

    match email {
        Ok(email) => HttpResponse::Ok().json(email),
        Err(e) => {
            log::error!("Failed to create email: {:?}", e);
            HttpResponse::InternalServerError().finish()
        }
    }
}

That uses the struct:
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, FromRow)]
pub struct CreateEmail {
    pub subscriber_id: String,
    pub email: String,
}

And responds to an API request.
The problem is that it throws the following error in the IDE:
the trait bound `std::string::String: std::convert::From<std::option::Option<std::string::String>>` is not satisfied [E0277] Help: the following other types implement trait `std::convert::From<T>`: `std::string::String` implements `std::convert::From<&mut str>` `std::string::String` implements `std::convert::From<&std::string::String>` `std::string::String` implements `std::convert::From<&str>` `std::string::String` implements `std::convert::From<Box<str>>` `std::string::String` implements `std::convert::From<Cow<'_, str>>` `std::string::String` implements `std::convert::From<PgCiText>` `std::string::String` implements `std::convert::From<bytestring::ByteString>` `std::string::String` implements `std::convert::From<char>` `std::string::String` implements `std::convert::From<url::Url>` Note: required for `std::option::Option<std::string::String>` to implement `Into<std::string::String>`

I have been trying to debug this for the last 7 hours and have no idea how to proceed.
Any help would be appreciated.
